# Why is the ghost on the uniform patch making a peace sign?

Tags: ghostbusters-2

In *Ghostbusters 2*, why is the [patch on the uniform giving a peace sign](http://www.gbfans.com/w/images/f/f4/237_8714896282.jpg)? Obviously in the context of the real world the new logo makes sense.  However, in the reality of the movie, why would they make a patch that basically looks like a symbol meaning "No ghosts offering peace"?

Comment: Could be V for victory rather than being a peace symbol.

Comment: I really like your thought but can you back it with references?

Comment: Well, why do you think it is a peace sign in the first place? It could be a two (when counting anglosaxon), a ny for nike, a v for victory, or a peace sign. The only thing that immediately makes sense -out of universe- is the two. I can't remember any preference for one or the other in universe except for the cheap trick that Walt explained, which favors the two. (Personal note: Reading it without context as peace sign would be the last item on my preference list.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing the (rather flimsy) in-movie excuse is that it's supposed to illustrate they're back in business, which is emphasized in [the (deleted) full version](http://www.theraffon.net/~spookcentral/gb2_deleted08.htm) of their in-movie TV commercial:

> STANTZ: That's right -- Ghostbusters. **We're back** and we're better than ever with **twice** the know-how and **twice** the particle-power to deal with all your supernatural elimination needs... And to celebrate our grand reopening, we're giving you **twice** the value with our special half-price **'Welcome Back'** service plan.

Comment: This was actually in the movie on the Netflix version.

Comment: The entire commercial? Good to know!

Comment: Yes, I believe we are soon going to live in a world where "Deleted Scenes" a thing of the past. I think these "non essential" scenes were usually removed because VHS/DVD could only store so many minutes.

Answer (score 5):

I never thought of this as a peace sign; I always just thought of it as two fingers for the number two, as in "Ghostbusters II". This makes more sense in the context of the original poster.

[image: Ghostbusters II]

Comment: Er, that's not what Mr. Manager asked. I think he's aware that it refers to the sequel *in reality*; he was just wondering how they explain the sign *in the movie*, where it makes less sense and it just looks like a ghost making a peace sign.

Comment: @Walt Well, the answer to this seems *"not"*.