# Were all the ghosts in the Ghost Busters movie 'evil'?

Tags: ghostbusters-2, ghostbusters

As per the title, is there any evidence that some of the ghosts in the *Ghostbusters* movies were benign?

For clarification, 'evil' in the respect that all seemed to go out of their way to terrorise New Yorkers and apparently, not much else.

Comment: Slimer certainly seemed more concerned with eating than terrorizing.

Comment: @Roger True but as soon as Peter confronted him, Slimer did charge and that seemed 'aggressive' to me at least.

Comment: I always saw them as having plenty of irresponsible fun, with no intention of hurting anyone *per se*, but not minding to do it either as a part of their amusement. I'm not sure that "evil" would be the right word for that.

Comment: I agree with @VedranŠego. Very apt description of the ghosts. I really never saw the main contingent of ghosts to be "evil" ... Now Gozer was a whole different ball of ectoplasm.

Comment: And the librarian lady just wanted everyone to "shoosh". Until they got on her bad side.

Comment: Well, in the end [all they wanted was peace](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21542/49). ;-)

Comment: @MarkRowlands: Any reason you deleted your Forrest Gump question? I literally hit the answer button as you deleted it! It was a good question.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Oh sorry, it was just literally after posting the question I found it. I felt rather foolish!

Comment: @MarkRowlands: No worries. Feel free to bring it back if you want (and even answer your own question). It's actually a fascinating one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the ghosts in the Ghostbuster series seem content to ignore humans unless in significant curcumstances. For instance, the [Library Ghost](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Library_ghost) is not causing any harm. She's just scary  to people because she's a ghost. She's not aggressive until the Ghostbusters show up, and only then, just long enough to escape.

> When the future Ghostbusters were about to act out Ray's plan to "get her", she changed into a terrifying form and scared them away. She was never seen or heard from again until 1991

Also, [Slimer](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Slimer) has been known to employees of the Sedgewick Hotel for a long time. The only reason the Ghostbusters are called in, is that increased activity was making it more difficult to keep Slimer a secret. Like the Library Ghost, Slimer only got aggressive when threatened.

> Slimer was a legendary ghost to all on the original staff of the Sedgewick Hotel. His usual territory was the twelfth floor, but his outings were usually non-violent and simply involved eating food. As a result, the hotel was able to keep a lid on the supernatural problems (for a while). For some reason, Gozer's approaching time of arrival provoked Slimer (and many other ghosts) into being much more active than usual. Eventually the staff couldn't keep the ghost a secret anymore and called the Ghostbusters.

As a matter of fact, of the 9 ghosts listed in the [Ghostbusters Wikia](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Ghostbusters_Wiki), only 4 are overtly evil. Gozer, Gozer's minions (Zuul [the gatekeeper] and Vinz Clortho [the keymaster]), and the Stay Puft Marshmallow Man (which is actually just Gozer's Earth form).

Answer (score 4):

In Ghostbusters 2, Slimer drove Louis Tully (Rick Moranis) to the Art Gallery in a bus so he could help fight Viggo the Carpathian.

That's a pretty nice thing to do.

[image]

Comment: I deleted this answer because I didn't ask it here, I asked it elsewhere.